# TFS2008 - packaging in MSI and cab file for installer project

Tags: msbuild, windows-installer, cab

I am using automated build and installer project to create msi file in TFS 2008. There I need to create a big folder structure having thousands of file and having size of hundreds of MB on user machine when user installs using MSI file. Using TFS installer project, if I add individual file then my installer.vdproj becomes really big and unmaintainable.

So is there a good way to handle these bunch of files as single unit? I can think of compression mechanism for now, which has two parts: -

1. How to compress the files into a cab file(in MSBulid process may be)? It seems the makecab command only takes one file at a time?
2. How to modify installer project so that cab file is part of MSI and on user's machine the cab file is uncompressed to create the folder structure? can I have cab file as well as MSI (so that cab file is not part of MSI) ? rest of the dlls go into MSI.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Tools from the Windows Install SDK such as [MSIFILER.EXE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370108%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) can be easily scripted to load a whole directory of files (for example) into the MSI's file store or the CAB.</strike>

In your case, you would want to configure the script to be run as a [post-build event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), so that first you build the setup project's MSI then the script modifies it.

You are correct that makecab.exe only takes one file at a time. You can use a [CMD shell FOR-loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) to add them one-by-one (e.g. `FOR /F %%file IN ('dir /b /s') DO makecab %%file output.cab`). Personally, I prefer [archive tools like 7-zip](http://7-zip.org/) which are also [scriptable from the command line](http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples).

There are several methods to add the files to the Windows Installer package (e.g. [WiImport.vbs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369227%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [MAKEMSI](http://dennisbareis.com/makemsi.htm), or [manually](http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/add-file-msi-using-orca))...

..but maybe you don't want to do that. I think it might be better to just include the archive (zip, cab, whatever) and [create a custom action in the setup project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9k65z2d.aspx) to extract it during the install.

Comment: Thanks for help. but I couldn't use msifiler, the syntax is "msifiler.exe -d {database} [-v] [-h] [-s ALTSOURCE]" so database is my project.msi file. I don't need -h option as existing files aleady have table entry. so where do I mention my files that I want to push into msi. This also doesn't allow creating cab file.

Comment: Ooh, sorry about that--that must not be the right one! (It's been a while since I was actively packaging MSIs.) Looking for better options now...